# Can I assign object of base class to the object of its subclass?

Tags: java, .net

Consider the following code:

```
    public interface Vegetarian{}
    public class Animal{}
    public class Deer extends Animal implements Vegetarian{}
    Deer d = new Deer();
    Animal a = d;
```

In this example, `Animal` is a base class and `Deer` is a subclass, and I am assigning a `Deer` object to the object of `Animal` class, so object 'a' refers to the object of `Deer` (i.e. 'd'). My question is can I write it vice versa, as follows?

```
    Deer d = a;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with an explicit cast, but it will throw a ClassCastException if `a` doesn't refer to an actual `Deer`.

```
Deer d = (Deer) a;
```

Comment: so if 'a' refers to the object of deer, it will not throw this exception right?